# How to use Rails with uppercase column name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have the following as part of an AR query:

`.having('COUNT(foo.id) > bar.maxUsers')`

This generates an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column bar.maxusers does not exist
                                                                    ^
       HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "bar.maxUsers".
```

I am referencing the column `bar.maxUsers`.

So, apparently AR downcases the query. How to suppress this behavior?

Rails 4.2.10
PostgreSQL

EDIT: SQL:

```
SELECT ... HAVING COUNT(foo.id) > bar.maxUsers
```

So it is happening after the `to_sql`. Maybe from the `execute`?

Comment: Can you try to add `to_sql` at the end of the query and post the rendered query please ?

Comment: Interesting... Haven't seen this before, but I might try using Arel, to see if it mangles it, too... (I'm assuming you can't easily adjust the column name to something more Railsy)

Comment: @Shiko - Please see update.

Comment: Maybe you did not use the table name in plural form?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't an ActiveRecord or AREL issue, this is just how case sensitivity works in SQL and PostgreSQL.

Identifiers in SQL (such as table and column names) are case-insensitive unless they're quoted. Standard SQL says that unquoted identifiers are folded to upper case, PostgreSQL folds them to lower case, hence the `bar.maxusers` in the error message.

The solution is to quote the offending column name:

```
.having('COUNT(foo.id) > bar."maxUsers"')
```

Note that you must use double quotes for quoting the identifier as single quotes are only for string literals. Also note that identifier quoting is database-specific: standard SQL and PostgreSQL use double quotes, MySQL uses backticks, SQL Server uses brackets, ...