# Selecting column with uppercase name from joined table Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using Ruby Active Record and have 3 postgres database tables:

1. employee_city - contain foreign keys to employee and city tables
2. city
3. employee

The associations are set up in such a way, that I can use the ORM to join all the tables:

`employee_country_joined = employee_country.joins(:country, :employee)`

To search `employee_country_joined` by a country and return an array of employees in that country I can do:

`employee_country_joined.where('country.name': 'US').pluck('employee.name')`

The problem is there are uppercase columns in the joined database tables so if I try:

`employee_country_joined.where('country.Other_column': 'something')`

I get an error saying `country.other_column does not exist`.  It seems the column names are automatically lowercased and `prevents selecting a column in a joined table with an uppercase column name`.  Works fine when the column name is all lowercase.  Is there a way to do a case-sensitive select on a joined table with an uppercase column name?

Solution:

`employee_country_joined.pluck('country."Other_column"')`

Comment: check this please:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994652/how-to-use-rails-with-uppercase-column-name
does it solve your question?

Comment: yes it does.  thank you kind sir.